# Can't connect to a node.js server on my VPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, vps

Well, I hope this question isn't silly or repeated. I promise I have researched and tested a lot.

I've have a **server** on my VPS with this code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8080);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('hello', function() {
    console.log('Hello received');
  }
}
```

And a **client** in another machine:

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://[VPS Public IP]:8080');
  io.emit('hello');
</script>
```

This works when using private IP addresses and the same net. When using public IP this doesn't work. Any idea of why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there's a firewall on the VPS blocking the port? Is node binding to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: It's a VPS running with Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried to disable ufw (default firewall for Ubuntu), but my VPS has not installed it, so I suppose there is no firewall. Am I right?

I've substituted server.listen(8080) with server.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0") and nothing changes.

Comment: Verify connectivity by command `telnet VPS_Public_IP 8080`

Comment: Successfully connected with telnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more testing I've fixed my own problem.

I realized that VPS public IP (**X.X.X.209**) is different than the IP Address they give me to connect via SSH (**X.X.X.221**) using the Serial Console tool.

I was using this second IP Address **X.X.X.221** when my real public IP is the first one. Once I've used **X.X.X.209**, it has connected without any problem.

Thank you for all your comments and ideas.